# Summations of values from 1 to whatever user enters

Tags: python-3.x

def summation (intValue):

This function returns the summation of 1 to intValue. For example, summation (5) would return 15 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5). How would you do this? Use for loops?

Comment: Did you *try* using for loops? What happened? Give a [mcve] of your code; this isn't a code-writing or tutorial service.

Comment: you dont need to - 1+2+3+4+..10 = (1+10)+(2+9)+(3+8)+(4+7)+(5+6)=10*11/2 - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF